# SSRS Report Subscription Parameters (Date Values)

Tags: date, reporting-services, parameters, subscription

I am looking to setup a report subscription in SSRS 2008 R2 where the client user can set the date parameter to whatever the individual user would like. I have been reading multiple suggestions to use =Today() in the parameters but this syntax does not work for me. Does anyone know whether is is possible to set my from date to "Today -30 days" and my to date to "today"? What is the syntax used in the subscription parameters?

Settings:
[image]

Error:
[image]

Comment: check this article http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/535c7e0a-75e2-47d0-8b18-60d1e94805a2

Comment: Thanks praveen, I implemented the described solution and it is working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

As described in the above link provided by praveen the solution became to create two parameters in the report containing integer values with a label that describes the periods i would like to use in my subscription. These parameters can easily be set to "Hidden" so they are not showing when you would like to run the report by hand. I also chose to set the default value for both parameters to 1 which is my value for Today(). This mean my report will start out with having today's date selected in both of the visible date parameters.

In the two date parameters that are shown in the report you can then set the default value to a switch of the values you are able to pick in your hidden date parameters. You can now setup a subscription that will work and that looks like the following:

[image]