# SSRS Subscription allow for today or yesterday parameters SQL Server 2012

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, sql-server-2012, subscription

I have a user request to create a SSRS subscription that would fire daily and would provide content from yesterday's date until the time of running the report.

The report as designed through visual studio does have a minimum and maximum date at the time of running the report. However selecting a date range on the subscription and to have it dynamically move forward is not an option. Neither is entering parameters in the subscription screen. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: have you tried to use `Show or Hide` the dataset with expression?

Comment: This may assist you. Essentially you need to make your parameters dynamic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12039295/ssrs-report-subscription-parameters-date-values or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38273583/need-to-set-a-date-parameter-on-an-ssrs-subscription

Answer (score 2):

I usually take parameters that are the number of days from the current day to use as your date range.

For instance:

```
create proc my_report(@start_date_offset int, @end_date_offset int)
as
begin
  declare @start_date date;
  declare @end_date date;

  select
    @start_date = dateadd(dd, -1 * @start_date_offset, getdate()),
    @end_date = dateadd(dd, -1 * @end_date_offset, getdate());

  -- Do stuff with @start_date and @end_date

end
```

You can then call your report with these relative offsets instead of actual dates.

You can use actual datetimes and define offsets in hours or minutes instead, the overall principle is that your SSRS subscription has an offset as its hard-coded parameter, not an actual date.

---

Edit:

Another approach would be to have the stored proc only take date variables, but the SSRS report can have hidden offset parameters and visible date parameters.  The date parameters can have their default values calculated from the offsets, and the user can be allowed to override them.  Your SSRS subscription would specify the offsets, and have the date variables set to use the default values.

Comment: My problem is that I still need to have the report available to be run with users entering their own parameters. It's simply the scheduling of this subscription where I want to allow a specific user to default to yesterdays date.

Comment: You can have the offsets be hidden parameters, not visible when running the report manually, and default the date parameters to null.  At the start of the proc, test if the date parameters are null, and if so calculate new ones using offsets.  The subscription can set the date parameters to null and specify the offsets instead.